# how to display error message on server side validation in spring mvc

Tags: java, jquery, spring, validation, jsp

```js
//This is my loginController.java

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class LoginController
{
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String login(@RequestParam(value="userid", required=true) String userid,
         @RequestParam(value="password", required=true) String password,
         @RequestParam(value="confirmpassword", required=true) String confirmpassword,
         @RequestParam(value="role", required=true) String role,
         Map<String, Object> model)
 
 {
      if(userid.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,24}$") && password.matches("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{5,15}$")
      && confirmpassword.matches("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{6,20}$") 
      && (role.equals(new String("OPS(Operational)"))||role.equals(new String("Helpdesk"))))
      {
       model.put("userid", userid);
       model.put("password", password);
       model.put("confirmpassword", confirmpassword);
       model.put("role", role);
       
       System.out.println("successful!");
       return "page2";
      }
       else
       {
        return "login";
       }
     }

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 {
  String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
     String password = request.getParameter("password");
     String confirmpassword = request.getParameter("confirmpassword");
     String role = request.getParameter("role");
     
     try
     {
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }
     catch (ServletException e)
     {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 
   }
 
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
 {
  String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
     String password = request.getParameter("password");
     String confirmpassword = request.getParameter("confirmpassword");
     String role = request.getParameter("role");
  
     request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
 } 
}
```

```html
//This is my login.jsp file

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ include file="include.jsp" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>

<div align="center" id='formlogin' class="container">

<form method="post" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="login.htm">
  <table class="tableprop" border="0" width="90%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  
  <h3> Add a new user </h3>
  
   <tr>
    <td align="center">User ID:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="5" size="20" type="text" name="userid" id="userid" value="<%=request.getParameter("userid")!=null?request.getParameter("userid"):""%>"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center">Password:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="5" size="20" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<%=request.getParameter("password")!=null?request.getParameter("password"):""%>"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center">Confirm Password:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="5" size="20" type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" value="<%=request.getParameter("confirmpassword")!=null?request.getParameter("confirmpassword"):""%>"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center">Role:</td>
    <td><select name="role" id="role" title="Please select role" tabindex="5" value="<%=request.getParameter("role")!=null?request.getParameter("role"):""%>"/>
     <option value="">Select a specific role</option>
     <option value="OPS(Operational)">OPS(Operational)</option>
     <option value="Helpdesk">Helpdesk</option>
    </select></td>
   </tr>
   
   <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4"><input tabindex="7" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="submit"/></td>     
   </tr>
<!--    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm in a dialog</div> -->
   </table>    
  </form>
 </div>

<script>
 // just for the demos, avoids form submit
 jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
 debug: true,
 success: "valid"
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have added here 2 files.
first one is `loginController.java`
and other one is `login.jsp`
i have done client side validation in jquery.
now i want to display error message on server side validation in `loginController.java` file which has code for server side validation. and also i want it to be check once whether `loginController.java` is written correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring Validator interface to build your own custom validator and use spring form tags.

```
       User.java
       package com.expertwebindia.beans;
        public class User {
            private String name;
            private String email;
            private String address;
            private String country;
            private String state;
            private String city;
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getAddress() {
                return address;
            }

            public void setAddress(String address) {
                this.address = address;
            }

            public String getCountry() {
                return country;
            }

            public void setCountry(String country) {
                this.country = country;
            }

            public String getState() {
                return state;
            }

            public void setState(String state) {
                this.state = state;
            }

            public String getCity() {
                return city;
            }

            public void setCity(String city) {
                this.city = city;
            }

            public String getEmail() {
                return email;
            }

            public void setEmail(String email) {
                this.email = email;
            }



        }

                UserValidator.java



package com.expertwebindia.validators;
                import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
                import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
                import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
                import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

                import com.expertwebindia.beans.User;
                @Component
                public class UserValidator implements Validator
                {

                    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
                        return User.class.equals(clazz);
                    }
                    public void validate(java.lang.Object arg0, Errors arg1) {
                          ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "name", "name.required", "Name is required.");
                          ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "email", "Name.required", "Email is required.");
                          ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "address", "name.required", "Address is required.");
                          ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "country", "country.required", "Country is required.");
                          ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "state", "state.required", "State is required.");
                          ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "city", "city.required", "City is required.");
                    }

                }

    In controller you need to the following code to validate your bean.
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String doLogin(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm,
                BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {
            validator.validate(userForm, result);
            System.out.println("Email:"+userForm.getEmail());
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "register";
            }else{

                return "success";
            }
        }

    Please find more details about this in link below.
    http://www.expertwebindia.com/spring-3-mvc-custom-validator-example/
```

Comment: Sir I m ok with code change.
 but I have question : Can i not make changes in loginController file ?

Comment: Yes you can put error messages to model and then display in jsp page where required using JSTL <c:out value="error_message">. In loginController you don't need to write doPost and doGet methods just map your methods with URI using @RequestMapping

Comment: can you plz post here that small snippet of java code to model for single field ?

Comment: In controller in else condition you need to add validation for each input field
else
{
 if(userid.isEmpty()){
  model.put("userIdError","Please enter user name");
 }
 return "login";
 }


in jsp 
<tr>
 <td align="center">User ID:</td>
 <td><input tabindex="5" size="20" type="text" name="userid" id="userid" value="<%=request.getParameter("userid")!=null?request.getParameter("userid"):""%>"/></td>
 <td><c:out value="userIdError"/></td>
</tr>

Comment: Is your else block executed or not?

Comment: No it is not getting executed. but the text "userIdError" is coming on the webpage besides of user id textbox field which is because of the code written in td c:out tag in jsp file.

Comment: You should add validation of input properly to work properly.

Comment: Ok sir. I will try it. And i think c:out tag alone is not sufficient to display error.  I think I will need c:if tag also.

Comment: Yes you need to put c:out under <c:if test="${not empty error}"></c:if>

Comment: Sir i have not got solution of this question yet. Can you please help me?

Comment: What actually issue you're facing.I think you should first go for simple validation.

Comment: boolean validated = true;

if(userid.isEmpty()){

 validated = false;
 model.put("useridError","Please enter user id");
}
if(password.isEmpty()){
 validated = false;
 model.put("passwordError","Please enter password");
}
if(confirmpassword.isEmpty()){
 validated = false;
 model.put("confirmpasswordError","Please enter confirmpassword");
}
and so on

if(validated){

 succespage
}else{

  login page
}

}

Comment: When I click on submit button, the control goes to the server and returns back without showing any error. And I want that if userid is empty then it should show an error which it is not showing in the current case. I have added server side validations in loginController.java file. I have also added the lines as per u told in jsp as well as in java file. I have to check whether server side validation are working or not. So it should an error message. I have gone for simple validation.

Comment: It's working fine for yours.As I told you for simple validation first to check the flow and then customize the validation condition later.

Comment: Ok sir. I m still working on it. I will give it more tries.!